# register_sidebar() WordPress with bootstrap 3 collapse

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

Hi i am building a custom Wordpress theme and woocommerce theme. I need the sidebar to collapse using bootstrap. It will work if i can just get the %1$s to change or add my own variables here using a date function to give them a unique id.

```html
function onlinerugstorecustom_widgets_init() {
 register_sidebar( array(
  'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'onlinerugstorecustom' ),
  'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
  'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'onlinerugstorecustom' ),
  'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget panel panel-defualt %2$s">',
  'after_widget'  => '</div></div></div>',
  'before_title'  => '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="%1$s"><span class="plus-minus">+</span><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">',
  'after_title'   => '</a></h4></div>   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                  <div class="panel-body">',
 ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'onlinerugstorecustom_widgets_init' );
```

I have figured out a jQuery way to change the relative id's and labells but i would still like to know if there is a way to do this in php the %1$s simply won't work.

This is the jQuery i used and it works now.

```js
(function($){
    
  //Change ids and attributes on sidebar nav toggle as wordpress couldn't seem to do it.
  
  $('.panel').each(function( index ) {
      $(this).find('.panel-heading').attr('id', 'heading' + index);
      $(this).find('.panel-collapse').attr('id', 'toggle' + index);//$(this).attr('aria-labelledby')
      $(this).find('.panel-collapse').attr('aria-labelledby', 'heading' + index);
      
      $(this).find('.panel-title a').attr('href', '#toggle' + index);
      $(this).find('.panel-title a').attr('aria-controls', 'toggle' + index);
      

     });  
      
 });
```

Comment: I found a similar thread here but the answer didn't seem to work for me https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-echo-widget-in-before_title-and-after_title

Comment: Did you find a way to do it with wordpress? Your jQuery is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the (always unique) variable `%1$s`. Like so:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'onlinerugstorecustom' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'onlinerugstorecustom' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget panel panel-default %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div></div></div>',
    'before_title'  => '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab"><span class="plus-minus">+</span><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#%1$s" href="#%1$s" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">',
    'after_title'   => '</a></h4></div>   <div id="%1$s" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                              <div class="panel-body">',
) );
```

I have removed the unique variable of the `before_widget` div and added it to the panel-body you want to collapse. Because id's always have to be unique for being valid HTML.

Comment: Thanks for this i was going to use javascript as a backup or i though of dropping the panels in as html widgets, this will mean they are not dynamic though. I will try your code thanks Luuk Skeur.

Comment: using javascript is not a bad thing, in your case you could bind the link to `parent().parent().next()` or even bind `panel-heading` to `panel-body`.

Comment: Thanks for some reason the %1$s won't work it might be because Woocommerce does extend the wc_widget Class. I did end up using jQuery for this as i don't know how to solve it in php but i wish i could just add variable in the array.